# Compiling OpenCV 2.3 with OpenNI and Qt

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv, cmake, kinect, openni

for a project that uses the Microsoft Kinect I currently would like to compile OpenCV with the OpenNI framework.

I already have OpenNI, NITE and the Kinect drivers installed but I am having problems compiling OpenCV so that I can develop using OpenNI.

For this I started cmake, took the OpenCV (2.3 release) sources, selected Visual Studio 2008 makefiles, linked all necessary paths, checked `"WITH_QT"` and `"WITH_OPENNI"`, set the paths to Qt files and the OpenNI include and lib folders as well as the PrimeSense folders and generated MakeFiles, which worked without errors.

I then started the `OpenCV.sln` solution that had been created by CMake, set it to Release and tried to build the whole package. Unfortunately it gives me an error:

http://pastebin.com/6L7wCx4r

I pasted it there since it's quite long. You can see the errors at about line 420.

Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong there and how I can fix it? Would be great if anybody could have a look at it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib")
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I have no idea on where to add this? Would be great if you could tell me...

Comment: At the beginning of a source file.

Comment: I added this line to a beginning of a source file with no effect though. I still get the same errors... Any other idea?